# RICOH THETA calibration

Tags: c++, ros, theta360

Sorry for the elementary question.
I am trying to run OpenVSLAM using RICOH THETA.
But I don't know how to calibrate THETA.
Is there a detailed calibration procedure somewhere?

Comment: This sounds like a question for the OpenVSLAM community. Have you contacted them?

Comment: I have submitted an application to the slack community, but I am still not able to join the community.
Therefore, no contact has been sent yet.

Answer (score 2):

After his was posted, the community developed an open source driver for Linux to stream the 5K video from the RICOH THETA Z1 to the Linux computer running OpenVSLAM to generate a real-time path. As the driver (which is a fork of libuvc) is new and opens up new uses of OpenVSLAM withe the RICOH THETA, wanted to share this info

https://community.theta360.guide/t/slam-with-ricoh-theta-using-openvslam/5104/17?u=craig

[image: OpenVSLAM]

Additional information on the Linux driver is here:

https://theta360.guide/special/linuxstreaming/

Comment: Nice work! But how did you do the calibration?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which THETA model you're referring to, and probably you mean programmatically. But here is the procedure for calibrating the compass: https://community.theta360.guide/t/ricoh-theta-z1-calibrate-your-compass/4543

Comment: Excuse me, my research has found the way. Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: Could you post your solution?